# Is it possible to have tabs in the new windows 10 bash terminal?

Tags: tabs, windows-subsystem-for-linux, windows-10-v1607

Is it possible to have tabs in the new windows 10 bash terminal? It would be really useful.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[ConEmu](https://conemu.github.io/) can run various shells, including Bash on Ubuntu on Windows and supports tabs (among many other niceties).

Answer (score 5):

I am using the terminator to use the windows 10 bash. You just need to install the Xming and the terminator with apt-get

https://sourceforge.net/projects/xming/

Answer (score 2):

I'm using [Hyper](https://hyper.is/), which has tabs. To use with WSL (bash) you need to edit the preferences file:

`shell: 'C:\\Windows\\System32\\bash.exe'`

Comment: can one have several instances of WSL bash running in it?

Comment: @DimaPasechnik Not sure exactly what you mean by "several instances", but you can have multiple tabs accessing different paths. Suggest you just download and give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to use tmux in all OS including windows (bash). You should definitely check them out [here](https://github.com/tmux/tmux.git). 
[Some advantages of using tmux over other multiplexers are:](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/231287/advantages-of-using-linux-terminal-multiplexers)

> 1. configurable scrollback (ie., number of lines to retain)
> 2. searchable scrollback
> 3. cut/copy and paste between clients (windows)
> 4. persistence across sessions
> 5. status line for system information
>
> The most significant benefit is persistence. Start a job in a multiplexer
> session and you can log off knowing that when you log back in and
> reattach the job will still be running.